# What's the support status of old JSF versions?

Tags: jsf, end-of-life, jsf-1.1

What is the official support status of older JSF releases like 1.1, 1.2, 2.0? Is there some end-of-life roadmap for JSF releases?

I was only able to find end-of-life roadmap for Java SE here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html  I couldn't find anything related to JEE specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a specification, JSF doesn't have a end-of-life date. That's usually used to describe available (commercial) support, which is available for the products based on that spec.

The support offerings are quite numerous, so I'll just point out [Jboss EAP](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap) and [Oracle WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/cloud-app-foundation/weblogic/suite/overview/index.html).

If you're looking for an answer regarding JSF support by component toolkits, there's the [Richfaces Support Matrix](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PrioritizedRichFacesBrowsersCompatibilityMatrix) and I've seen that Primefaces-4 supports JSF-2.x up to the latest 2.2 release.